# Autocomplete form and a hidden input

Tags: php, autocomplete

Basically, I have an input field in my form that is set in the CSS to `display: none` and I was wondering if auto fill programs fill in hidden fields?  I set the value of the field to time() on load and compare it to the time the form is submitted to tell if the user is a human or bot.

Here is my code for the hidden field:

```
<?php

    $loadTime = time(); // Initial time that the page loads is checked against the time the form is submitted and if its too fast, its probably a bot

?>

<input type="text" name="loadTime" id="loadTime" value="<?php echo $loadTime ?>" maxlenght="50" />
```

Comment: Being that you're using PHP, you could always store the load time in a session, and then compare that time once the form has been posted. No need to use form variables that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a text input with `display:none;` you should use `<input type="hidden" .../>`. Like this auto fill programs won't modify its value. Another (and safer) option is storing the time value as a server variable so that it can't be modified

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  I validate the post var on the server side to make sure the input is only a UNIX time stamp and if its not, I return an error.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if auto fill programs fill in hidden fields?

(**EDIT**: By hidden I thought that you were asking for this:

```
<input type="hidden"...
```

)

Answer is no. Also, I would remove that hidden field because somebody could manipulate that value. I would rather store that time data in session because it's stored on server and not on client's computer.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  And I already thought about the possibility of someone manipulating it and because of that, I validate the post var on the server side to make sure it's only a UNIX time stamp and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Even if auto filling fills the form, It won't be visible since it is set in CSS. If you want the text to become visible, change the class CSS while JavaScript changes / fills the input. You can do both filling text and change CSS both, at the same time, using JavaScript.